# Endereço tipo Struct para INT

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, lista-encadeada

Tenho a seguinte Struct:

```
struct nodo{
int elo_a;
char nick[26];
char cidade[16];
int idade;
int elo_p;};
```

Tenho as duas atribuições da struct:

```
struct nodo *variavel;
struct nodo *offline;
```

Ok, já inseri um valor na offline, setando `int elo_p` e `int elo_a` como NULL, já que se trata do primeiro elemento em uma lista duplamente encadeada. Agora eu insiro valores na struct variável e quero atribuir o endereço de memória da mesma para o `int elo_p` do meu primeiro registro da struct offline, fiz da seguinte forma `offline->elo_p = variavel;` mas aparece um erro dizendo: **invalid conversion from 'nodo*' to int**. Sei que poderia resolver o problema mudando a variável `int elo_p` para `struct nodo *elo_p` mas necessito guardar o endereço de memória dentro do `int elo_p`, existe alguma maneira?Ou estou fazendo algo muito errado?Código Completo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define TAM 30

struct nodo{
    int elo_a;
    char nick[26];
    char cidade[16];
    int idade;
    int elo_p;
};
struct nodo *variavel; // troquei variavel estatica por dinamica
struct nodo  l_dupla[TAM]; //pnd

int top = TAM - 1;

void cria_pnd(void){ // codigo disponivel no trabalho *pnd*
     int i = 0;
     while(i < TAM-1){
           l_dupla[i].elo_p = ++ i;
     }
     l_dupla[TAM-1].elo_p = -1;
}

int pilha_pop(void){// função tirar da pnd
    if(top >= 0)
    return (-- top);

}

struct nodo pilha_push(void){// função inserir na pnd
    if(top>=0){
        return  l_dupla[top];
        top++;
    }else
        printf("Vazio ou nao existe nodo\n");

}

struct nodo retirada(void){
        struct nodo n;
        n = pilha_push();
        return n;
}

void inserir(struct nodo *offline, struct nodo *online,struct nodo *ignorados){
    int sw,indice;
    indice = pilha_pop();

    variavel = (struct nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

    printf("Escolha em qual lista deve ser incluido o usuario \n 1 - offline  2 - online  3 - ignorados \n" );
    scanf("%d",&sw);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite os valores para o usuario \n");
    printf("nick:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("&s",variavel->nick);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("cidade:\n");
    scanf("%s",variavel->cidade);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("idade: \n");
    scanf("%d",variavel->idade);

    //inserir controle dos elos
    //inserir
    switch (sw){
        case 1:
            offline = (struct nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
            if(offline == NULL){
                offline = variavel;
                offline->elo_a = NULL;
                offline->elo_p = NULL;
            }else{
                offline->elo_p = variavel;
                variavel->elo_a = offline;

                offline = variavel;
                offline->elo_a = variavel->elo_a;
                offline->elo_p = NULL;
            }

            break;
        /*case 2:
        online = (struct nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
            online = &variavel;
          break;
        case 3:
            ignorados = (struct nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
            ignorados = &variavel;
            break;*/
        default:
            break;
   }
}
/*void mostar(void){
    int escolha = 0;
    printf("Digite a lista desejada: 1 - offline  2 - online  3 - ignorados:");
    scanf("%d",&escolha);

    switch (sw){
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:
            online = &variavel;
          break;
        case 3:
            ignorados = &variavel;
            break;
        default:
            break;
   }
}*/

int main()
{
    struct nodo *offline = NULL;
    struct nodo *online = NULL;
    struct nodo *ignorados = NULL;
    char ch;
    cria_pnd();

    do{
        printf(" _____________________________________\n|\t\tmenu \t\t      |\n|_____________________________________|\n");
        printf("| I- incluir R- Retirada M - Mostar   |\n| T - troca de status D - Nodos disp  |\n|\t        S- Sair\t\t      |\n");
        printf("|_____________________________________|\n ");
        fflush(stdin); //PRECISA DE 2 FFLUSH
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        fflush(stdin); //PRECISA DE 2 FFLUSH

        switch (ch){
            case ('I'):
                inserir(offline,online,ignorados);
                break;
            case 'R':
               //variavel  =retirada();
                break;
            case 'M':
                //mostrar();
                break;
            case 'D':
                printf("Nodos disponiveis:%d",top+1);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }while(ch!='S');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas o `elo_p` era suposto ser o ponteiro para o próximo elemento da lista? Se for o caso tem de ser declarado como `struct nodo *`. Se não for o caso a sua lista não contempla o ponteiro para o proximo elemento.

Comment: Não entendi porque você quer guardar o endereço da variável. Você pode postar o código completo? Só com isso fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Seu código não faz sentido. Ponteiros em máquinas 64 bits não podem ser armazenadora em sua completude dentro de inteiros, então você já está perdendo o endereço real aqui. Faça como o Isac apontou e trate as variáveis `elo_p` e `elo_a` como ponteiros, fazendo fazer sentido as atribuições em `cria_pnd`, ou então faça ele ser inteiro do começo ao fim e altere completamente as atribuições dentro do `switch` dentro da função `inserir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O problema

O maior problema de se guardar um `ponteiro` dentro de um `inteiro` é que um `ponteiro` pode ser maior que um `inteiro`, de forma que você poderá não conseguir acessar a região de memoria que você deseja, já que perdeu alguns `bytes` de informação quando passou um `ponteiro` para dentro de um `inteiro`.

Se você realmente precisa de guardar inteiro e endereços na mesma variável, você pode usar um `long long` no lugar de um `int` e compilar usando a flag `-fpermissive`, mas mesmo assim não será garantido que você terá um código que funcione para qualquer arquitetura.

---

## Exemplo de implementação

Abaixo mostrarei um exemplo de código usando essa estratégia que você está querendo, mas acho melhor pensar em uma forma mais segura de implementar esse código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo{
    long long elo_a;
    char nick[26];
    char cidade[16];
    int idade;
    long long elo_p;
};

struct nodo *variavel;
struct nodo *offline;

int main() {
    // Alocando memória para offline
    offline = (struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

    // Alocando memória para variavel
    variavel = (struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

    // Adicionando um valor a idade de variavel
    variavel->idade = 23;

    // Colocando o endereço de variavel para offline->elo_p
    offline->elo_p = variavel;

    // Acessando o endereço de variavel
    struct nodo *aux = offline->elo_p;

    // 23
    printf("%d\n", aux->idade);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile da seguinte forma

```
gcc exemplo.cpp -fpermissive
```

Comment: Mesmo assim, as implementações de `cri_pnd` e `inserir` se contradizem quanto a tipagem. Se fosse mais coerente/homogêneo, seria melhor...

Comment: De fato usar um ponteiro do tipo struct é mais confiável, queria saber as implicações em usar um int, agora faz mais sentido

Comment: Usar um `long long` para guardar um ponteiro para outro elemento não é de todo boa prática, especialmente quando não tem nenhuma vantagem neste caso, e ainda irá dificultar em debug e erros no futuro.. Deve no minimo de colocar na sua resposta que não é uma solução razoável, e dizer como deveria de ser feito.